# Is conduit required for running wiring in an attic?

Tags: electrical, wiring

Do I have to put the 120 volt wiring in my attic inside of conduit? I don't recall ever seeing any wiring inside of conduit in an attic but I'm not sure.

Comment: Try searching the site for questions dealing with wiring in attics, you should find quite a bit of useful information.

Comment: I appreciate everyone's patience with me being new to this site and your input has been most helpful!

Comment: I still have not had the time to merge my accounts but if I access the site through the app which I downloaded to my phone and use that route to use this site then it shouldn't be any problem hopefully

Answer (score 2):

No, conduit is NOT required in attics. Not unless conduit is required in your area.

There are other factors involved in wiring in attic spaces, but your question is a bit too vague to go into that.

Comment: Speedy Petey - thank you very much for your comment I'm just running a ceiling fan to each of the 3 bedrooms and the living room as there is no overhead lighting installed in the house they have two open spots on the breaker panel he wants me to use one to wire all four of the fans just wanted to make sure I did not need to put the wiring going through the attic in conduit I suppose I'm going to run it right across the bottom of the rafters

Answer (score 1):

You only have to put the wiring in conduit, if you have to protect it from physical damage.  i.e. If you're pulling individual wires, or cables are run in such a way that protection is required.

Without knowing what type of cable/wire you're installing, it's difficult to be more specific.

Comment: Or if you live in Chicago...;-)